# React-native bundle for WPF

Tags: wpf, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use react native to bundle an application for windows 7.

I found I can use windows wpf for this, https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows.

But when I use the following command to bundle the application 
   `react-native bundle --platform wpf --entry-file index.wpf.js--bundle-output wpf\tte\ReactAssets\index.wpf.bundle --assets-dest wpf\tte\ReactAssets`

I get "unsupported platform wpf"

I have followed the advice in this bug 
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/1263

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After bashing my head against this for a few days I found that the wpf plugin is deprecated and the platform to use is windows. So in the above command I change it to

```
--platform windows
```

and leave everything else the same it seems to work.